# How to filter label by regular expression?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

The filter by regex clause is ignored, `FILTER(!REGEX(STR(?aLabel), "^Q[0-9]+$"))`... How to use "filter by label?"

---

### Real case

```
SELECT ?a ?aLabel ?lat ?long WHERE {
  ?a wdt:P31 wd:Q274393 .   # bakery or scholl or etc.
  ?a p:P625 ?statement .    # that has coordinate-location statement

  ?statement psv:P625 ?coordinate_node .
  ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat .
  ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLongitude ?long .

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]" .
  }
  #FILTER(!REGEX(STR(?aLabel), "^Q[0-9]+$")) # not working, no items !  
  #FILTER(!REGEX(STR(?a), "^Q[0-9]+$")) # not working, ignored !
}
ORDER BY (?aLabel)  # need to eliminate ugly itens with no name
```

You can [edit here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fa%20%3FaLabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fa%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ274393%20.%20%20%20%23%20bakery%20or%20scholl%20or%20etc.%0A%20%20%3Fa%20p%3AP625%20%3Fstatement%20.%20%20%20%20%23%20that%20has%20coordinate-location%20statement%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20psv%3AP625%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLatitude%20%3Flat%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLongitude%20%3Flong%20.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2C%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23FILTER%28%21REGEX%28STR%28%3FaLabel%29%2C%20%22%5EQ%5B0-9%5D%2B%24%22%29%29%20%23%20not%20working%2C%20no%20items%20%21%20%20%0A%20%20%23FILTER%28%21REGEX%28STR%28%3Fa%29%2C%20%22%5EQ%5B0-9%5D%2B%24%22%29%29%20%23%20not%20working%2C%20ignored%20%21%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%28%3FaLabel%29%20%20%23%20need%20to%20eliminate%20ugly%20itens%20with%20no%20name).

---

PS: it is not the question, but another solution for the real-life problem, which is interesting to comment on, is a clause to check "no language labels" or "empty label".

Comment: the regex does not work because the labels like your `?aLabel` are magic vars that come from some special non-standard service, thus, happen after the query has been evaluated.

Comment: you can get rid of those entities without an English label by adding `FILTER EXISTS {?a rdfs:label ?someLabel filter(langmatches(lang(?someLabel), "en"))}`

Comment: PS: I am using `[AUTO_LANGUAGE]`  that is the semantic of "any language"... `filter(
       langmatches(lang(?someLabel), "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]")
     )`

Comment: Do not use label service (see above) or use it in the manual mode: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/SERVICE_-_Label#Manual_Label_SERVICE. "Auto language" doesn't mean "any language".

Comment: Hi @StanislavKralin, sorry, you correct `AUTO_LANGUAGE`  is not "any", but seems that is working fine as "check something exists".

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @UninformedUser,

> the labels like your `?aLabel` are magic vars that come from some special non-standard service, thus, happen after the query has been evaluated

so, to avoid magic, we can try to isolate it in a subquery... It is working fine!

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  # no constraints here in the main query, bypass the subquery
  { # subquery:
    SELECT ?a ?aLabel ?lat ?long 
    WHERE {
      ?a wdt:P31 wd:Q274393 .   # bakery or scholl or etc.
      ?a p:P625 ?statement .    # that has coordinate-location statement
      ?statement psv:P625 ?coordinate_node .
      ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat .
      ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLongitude ?long .
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]" . }
    }
    ORDER BY (?aLabel)  
  }
  FILTER(!REGEX(STR(?aLabel), "^Q[0-9]+$")) # to eliminate ugly itens with no name
}
```

See  or  [edit here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fa%20%3FaLabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fa%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ274393%20.%20%20%20%23%20bakery%20or%20scholl%20or%20etc.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fa%20p%3AP625%20%3Fstatement%20.%20%20%20%20%23%20that%20has%20coordinate-location%20statement%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20psv%3AP625%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLatitude%20%3Flat%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLongitude%20%3Flong%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2C%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20%28%3FaLabel%29%20%20%23%20need%20to%20eliminate%20ugly%20itens%20with%20no%20name%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20FILTER%28%21REGEX%28STR%28%3FaLabel%29%2C%20%22%5EQ%5B0-9%5D%2B%24%22%29%29%20%23%20not%20working%2C%20no%20items%20%21%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A).

### Optional solution to filter no-names

As commented in the end of the question,  another solution for the real-life problem, is a clause to check "no language labels" or "empty label". No regex and no subquery need, only add the above `FILTER EXISTS` on original query:

```
SELECT ?a ?aLabel ?lat ?long WHERE {
  ?a wdt:P31 wd:Q274393 .   # bakery or scholl or etc.
  ?a p:P625 ?statement .    # that has coordinate-location statement

  ?statement psv:P625 ?coordinate_node .
  ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat .
  ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLongitude ?long .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]" .
  }
  FILTER EXISTS {
    ?a rdfs:label ?someLabel filter(langmatches(lang(?someLabel), "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]"))
  } 
}
ORDER BY (?aLabel)
```

See or  [edit here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fa%20%3FaLabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fa%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ274393%20.%20%20%20%23%20bakery%20or%20scholl%20or%20etc.%0A%20%20%3Fa%20p%3AP625%20%3Fstatement%20.%20%20%20%20%23%20that%20has%20coordinate-location%20statement%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20psv%3AP625%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLatitude%20%3Flat%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLongitude%20%3Flong%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2C%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20FILTER%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fa%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FsomeLabel%20filter%28langmatches%28lang%28%3FsomeLabel%29%2C%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22%29%29%7D%20%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%28%3FaLabel%29)